# Creating menu for 2d game JavaFX

Tags: java, menu, javafx, 2d

I am working on a simple Space Invaders game in JavaFX.

What are some good practices for creating the game menu? (Start Game, Game Guide, High Scores, Exit)?

What are some good tutorials that you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a little looking around and I found this tutorial which looks pretty good in terms of [working with Canvas in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm).

As for your questions I am a little confused as to what exactly you are looking to answers for, but I will offer a couple little tips.

- A Menu Screen is not all that different from the Game Screen itself. They are both rendered onto the same window and they will both be required to accept input from the user.
- Your game will have multiple scenes, such as the Main Menu, the Game Screen, the End Screen. You will most likely be rendering these separately based on which screen they are currently at.
- All of these will be aware of your Game object, you will want to be able to launch the Game from the start menu or report on the players score at the End Screen.

If you have any more specific questions feel free to ask. Some other good sites for Game Design and Development are: [GameDev SO](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) and [GameDev.net](http://GameDev.net/)